# Apps given to testers are on production or debug environment?

Tags: ios, security, https

When we upload the app to Apple Store and internal testers or external testers download it, They get debug or production app?

I saw some way by which testers got my newtwork call details i.e. urls and parameters that am sending.
Even though I was using HTTPS

I was using the native API provided by apple i.e. URLSession.

Comment: What does prod/debug have to do with HTTPS? When using HTTPS only the requested domain / server name should be visible. Unless you log something.

Comment: @luk2302 I was thinking like in debug testers might get some data, Yeah I was printing the parameter and the response. I just commented the printing code so now testers will not be able to see. Right?

Comment: Logging does not generally depend on the environment unless you explicitly tell it to do so.

Comment: Those were just print() methods which I commented.

Comment: exactly, they log always, they do not care about the environment.

Comment: But the testers have installed the app from test flight link, then how they got these things!